# Does the temperature of a body depend on the frame of reference?

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity, temperature, reference-frames

Does the temperature of a body depend on the frame of reference?

Comment: To answer this question, one first needs a precise formulation of the "zero-law of thermodynamics" in special relativity, see https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.06396 (the transformation of temperature is also discussed).

Answer (score 2):

Temperature can be thought of as the vibration or oscillation of individual particles. More the vibration, more the temperature. The frames velocity is just the velocity of its mean position, as the vibration is independent of the frame velocity, so is the temperature.

Comment: Does this mean a vibrating body will have a higher temperature compared to the same body at rest?

Comment: You are talking about a visible scale of vibration. You must have read about Degree's of freedom. each degree of freedom contributes 0.5*k*T Joules of Vibrational energy, where T is temperature in kelvin and 'k' is the boltzmann constant. A body truly at rest will be at 0k.

Comment: The monatomic ideal gas model is a clear counterexample of your classification of temperature as vibration/oscillation