# Is the temperature of a gas affected by the motion of its container?

Tags: thermodynamics

Is temperature a reference frame dependent quantity?

Comment: This question is duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90343/why-isnt-temperature-frame-dependent?noredirect=1&lq=1 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/186655/why-does-the-temperature-of-a-gas-inside-a-moving-container-not-increase-with-ve?rq=1 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/245123/why-does-the-temperature-of-the-gas-in-a-container-moving-with-constant-velocity?rq=1 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/256159/does-the-temperature-of-a-body-depend-on-the-frame-of-reference?rq=1

Comment: and also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/418065/temperature-of-the-system-stays-constant-even-though-it-moves?rq=1

Comment: Tip: While asking a question, the sidebar mentions the questions which might contain an answer to your question. Do check them.

Comment: To answer this question, one first needs a precise formulation of the "zero-law of thermodynamics" in special relativity, see https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.06396 (the transformation of temperature is also discussed). How temperature transforms depends on the "thermometer" used!